# Git: keep multiple branches checked out

Tags: git, build

Each time I checkout a branch, I need to rebuild my project. This project has a long build process and I frequently switch branches so this wastes a lot of time. My solution has been to create local clones of the local repo, with different branches checked out in each clone, so that build scripts aren't faced with wholesale changes to the source each time I switch branches. The downside is that I've got to remember to keep the clones up to date.

Is there a better way to deal with this situation? If not, what are the best practices for maintaining multiple local clones?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [git-new-workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) for working with multiple checked out copies of the same repo. This will let you have a checked out copy of your repo for each branch (with all the build files involved), without the overhead of a full clone.

Comment: Thanks @meagar; git-new-workdir sounds promising. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: We're using Windows, so we got this working using [Dan Smith's Windows port of git-new-workdir](https://github.com/dansmith65/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir-win) and running Git bash as admin.